# Alter field in mongodb while ensuring uniqueness thereof in subset of documents

Tags: mongodb, set, unique

Suppose I have a collection of documents with the format:

```
{'_id': [numeric id]
 'set': [user determined set name],
 'uid': [user determined item id]
 }
```

All `uid`s must be unique within a `set` at all times. Given that constraint, is there a way to write a method that takes a `set`, an existing `uid`, and new `uid` as input and changes the existing uid to the new uid, while ensuring uniqueness, but without using a compound unique index on `set` and `uid`? Since findAndModify() only works on one document at a time, I'm not sure this is possible.

Alternatively, if there's a problem with the document structure itself, input is appreciated there as well.

Comment: If you're trying to ensure uniqueness (or find a document quickly), why wouldn't you want to use an index?

Comment: @WiredPrairie because it slows writes and requires more server memory. I also simply want to understand if this operation is possible without a unique index. Perhaps it isn't.